# How to make every parameter on the next line with AlignAfterOpenBracket=BlockIndent?

Tags: clang-format

I have the following clang-format configuration

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 80
IndentWidth: 4
```

And my code is formatted like this:

```
void f() {
    mapper.setCallback(CallbackType(someRandomParam11111111111111111111111111111)
    );
}
```

So only one parenthesis is on the next line.
It becomes as expected only if parameter has a few more symbols.

Tried lots of different options but none seems to be working.
Used clang-format 14 and 18.

I'd like to make it like this:

```
void f() {
    mapper.setCallback(
        CallbackType(someRandomParam11111111111111111111111111111)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ColumnLimit: 0` to avoid lines merging.

Also you should probably change `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` to `BreakBeforeBraces: Attach` to keep the opening brace on the same line.

With these two changes I got the following formatting:

```cpp
void f() {
    mapper.setCallback(
        CallbackType(someRandomParam)
    );
}
```